# How to safely remove multi linked documents and folders from one location in google drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, recycle-bin

We use the multi-linking of folders and documents in Google drive to share live updates with our whole team. This is very useful as each person gets access to the doc and any updates made are received in real-time.

The trouble we have is that if anyone decides to remove the multi-linked item from their home directory using the "remove" option, the content is trashed for everyone. This causes loss of data and info and is not acceptable. We do have the option of checking the location of the multi-linked item and removing it from that particular location alone. But not everyone follows this.

Is there any way we can do the settings such that the "remove" option works only on the current location for the multi-linked item? All ideas are welcome. Can we use Google App Script for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no workaround for this as of now.

However, you can [file a Feature Request](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6284762) for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for you to alter how the google Drive web application works.  Remove will remove it forever one.